# embeds_many, get grandchildren

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :user_topics
end


class UserTopic
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user
  embeds_many :user_topic_examples
end
```

and

```
class UserTopicExample
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user_topic
end
```

How can I get all user_topic_examples that belongs to a specific user:

**user.user_topic_examples**

or

**user.user_topics.user_topic_examples**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite straightforward:
UPDATED

```
def user_topic_examples
  user_topics.inject([]) {|result, ut| result + ut.user_topics_examples }
end
```